# Mocha test timing out

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

My mocha test doesn't seem to stop once the done call is called. I'm kinda stumped as it looks pretty much identical to everything I can find online.

This is the entirety of the test.js file.

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../app.js');

describe('GET /', function() {
  it('Should be status code 200', function(done) {
    request(app).get('/').expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

and this is my app.js

```
// set variables for environment
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// Set port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 4000));
// Views as directory for all template files
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); // use either jade or ejs       
// Instruct express to server up static assets
app.use(express.static('public'));
// Set routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
// Main
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
module.exports = app;
```

I get this output

> Node app is running on port 4000   GET /
>       âœ“ Should be status code 200 (141ms)
>
> 1) "after all" hook for "Should be status code 200"
>
> 1 passing (2s)   1 failing
>
> 1)  "after all" hook for "Should be status code 200":
>        Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test

.

Comment: What are you exporting from app.js?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `listen` from app.js. This is where the supertest API is getting confused. Remove:

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

And stick in a separate module. `app.js` should only export `app` so you can test it.

Comment: Still hangs with app.listen totally removed and all the tutorials and other git projects i see use the app.listen (see: https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter/blob/master/app.js)

Answer (score 0):

I would change your test. I'm not sure that you need to require your app.js.  You are calling bad request. Instead of calling request on app file, you should define your endpoint url and request that. Change your test to something like this:

```
var request = require('supertest');

var url = "http://yourapi.com:4000";
this.timeout(15000);

describe('GET /', function() {
  it('Should be status code 200', function(done) {
    request(url).get('/').expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

You can also set this.timeout to 15s in case that your request would need more time to finish. At least you know that it works correctly but is slow.